# Beginner javascript question: arrow function as optional argument

Tags: javascript

I am having a hard time understanding the following class declaration: it seems that `element` is default to `undefined`, but I have no idea why

1. is `(x, y)` in the `element = (x,y) => undefined` necessary; is `(x,y)` a abbreviated way of specifying array elements inside `element` object?
2. use `element(x, y)` to access array elements inside `element`?

```
class Matrix {
  constructor(width, height, element = (x, y) => undefined) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.content = [];

    for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        this.content[y * width + x] = element(x, y);
      }
    }
  }

let matrix = new Matrix(2, 2, (x, y) => `value ${x},${y}`);
```

The code is from Chapter 6 of [Eloquent JS](https://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html) booke

Comment: element is a function that returns undefined, xy are function's parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`element` is being set to an arrow function expression that takes two arguments and returns `undefined`. This code would be equivalent:

```
constructor (width, height, element) {
  if (!element) element = (x, y) => undefined
}
```

And these two are mostly equivalent with the scope caveat (`this` in the version with the `function` keyword refers to that function):

```
(x, y) => undefined
function (x, y) { return undefined }
```

Either way it's written, `element` is a function that, by default (if no third parameter is passed when instantiating an instance of that class), will take two parameters `x` and `y` and return `undefined`.

Comment: so in the constructor parameter, `element` is set to the anonymous function if as an optional argument; and in the constructor body, the anonymous function is invoked again with `element(x, y)` to process each array element in the `element` object?

Comment: `element` isn't an object that has arrays, it's a function. `x` and `y`  are coming from the variables set in the two `for` loops. In the last line of the code in your question, you're defining it as a function that takes that x and y and returns the two as a comma-separated string, which, in the class, means that `this.content[y * width + x]` would be `value 1,1` for example. The data it's acting on are the `x` and `y` (which are in turn based on the `width` and `height` constructor parameters).